# Unable to get Google API access token using auth code - redirect uri mismatch

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use the Google API PHP Client library to create a folder in the users Drive space. Unfortunately I keep getting a "redirect_uri_mistmatch Bad Request" error.

I've looked at several posts trying to resolve the issue to no avail. The steps I've already taken being,

- Verified URLs are all correct and current for my client ID in Google
  Developer console.
- Clearing and re-entering said URls in dev console.
- Updating client-secret.json file and manually verifying that URLs are
  making it into the file.
- Switched from drive_client->authenticate() to fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode() for error reporting.

The code is spread across 3 different files that all end up requiring each other at different points during execution - if that makes a difference, though I've tried combining everything into 1 file and still had the same issue.
My server is also running behind CloudFlare if that makes a difference, but I toggle developer mode when ever I am working on this.

**Generate oAuth request and redirect user:**

```
$this->_Google_Client = new Google_Client();
$this->_Google_Client->setAuthConfig("path/to/client_secret....json");
$this->_Google_Client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$this->_Google_Client->setAccessType("offline");
$this->_Google_Client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE);
$this->_Google_Client->setRedirectUri("https://example.org/accounts/settings/oAuthCallback.php");
$authUrl = $this->_Google_Client->createAuthUrl();

$_SESSION["oAuth_Action"] = "GDrive_API_Setup";//Used internally for something else
header("Location: " . $authUrl);
exit();
```

**Call Back**

```
$code = @$_GET["code"];
$this->_Google_Client = new Google_Client();
$this->_Google_Client->setAuthConfig("path/to/client_secret....json");
$this->_Google_Client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$this->_Google_Client->setAccessType("offline");
$this->_Google_Client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE);
$accessToken = $this->_Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
$this->_Google_Client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

echo var_dump($accessToken) . " -- " . $code; //Debug where I get error
```

**Exact Error**

```
array(2) { ["error"]=> string(21) "redirect_uri_mismatch" ["error_description"]=> string(11) "Bad Request" }
```

I left out the code for creating the actual file since it's not at issue (no I don't try and create the folder before retrieving the access token), as well as some other stuff in between where I make some calls to my database.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue before and it was because the redirect uri was not being set on the call back. Could you please add the following line:

```
$this->_Google_Client->setRedirectUri("https://example.org/accounts/settings/oAuthCallback.php");
```

To the callback, after the line:

```
$this->_Google_Client->setAccessType("offline");
```

so that it should be:

```
$this->_Google_Client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$this->_Google_Client->setAccessType("offline");
$this->_Google_Client->setRedirectUri("https://example.org/accounts/settings/oAuthCallback.php");
```

I hope that helps.